# Cassandra coordinator issue

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-2.1

We are having client side timeouts on a 6 node Cassandra 2.1.15 cluster.

Looking at those timeouts in details, we see that they rise only with two coordinators (the native client is enabled on the 6 nodes).

This is JMX informations about the coordinator latency on a sane node :
[image]

This is JMX informations about the coordinator latency on a node having problem :
[image]

Look at the 999thPercentile: about 40 milliseconds on the sane node and 5.6 seconds on the node having problem.
5.6 seconds are significantly higher than client timeout.

We will certainly try to decommission and replace the two nodes that causes timeouts but we would first like to understand what is happening.
What could explain such a different behaviour of coordinators? Do you have any idea of what could fix this?

Comment: Which load balancing policy are you using on the client side?  I recommend that devs use the TokenAware policy and then avoid access patterns which require coordinators to begin with (multi-key queries, table scans, batch updates).  It would also help to know the specific queries you are running during these periods of latency.

Comment: Thanks for advices @Aaron. In fact we already use TokenAwarePolicy. There are very much queries from multiple clients, it is hard to know which ones are running during these periods. Anyway, why would the running queries slow down always the same two nodes and not others ?